# How to find the location of _vimrc file in gvim on windows?

Tags: vim, vi

How to get the path of `_vimrc` file in gvim on windows.
I am currently working in one window and I want open `_vimrc` file in a split window.
Is there a command to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the following environment variable:

```
:sp $MYVIMRC
```

FWIW, asking random internet users on a generic site is not really the best or quickest way to get help on something in Vim. The built-in documentation answers most of your questions:

```
:help _vimrc
```